# How to populate a UITableViewCell with more than one item?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am totally new in iOS developing. I have a custom cell in my tableview. I have 32 images stored in a group named Images. Now I want to populate my tableview in such a way that one row of my cell contains 4 images. I am just a bit confused how to design it. Please help me.

This is my code..

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

 self.patternsArray = @[@"1.jpg",@"3.jpg",@"2.jpg",@"4.jpg",@"6.jpg",@"5.jpg",@"7.jpg",@"9.jpg",@"8.jpg",@"10.jpg",@"12.jpg",@"11.jpg",@"13.jpg",@"15.jpg",@"14.jpg",@"16.jpg", @"18.jpg",@"17.jpg",@"19.jpg",@"21.jpg",@"20.jpg",@"22.jpg",@"24.jpg",@"23.jpg", @"25.jpg",@"27.jpg",@"26.jpg",@"28.jpg",@"30.jpg",@"29.jpg",@"32.jpg",@"31.jpg"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableCell"];

_patternsString = [self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



UIImageView *imageView1 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_patternsString];


return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return [self.patternsArray count];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: your code shows that you are setting 1 imageview in each cell

Comment: You can use collectionView to show 3 images in device with

Comment: I have taken 4 imageviews with tags 1,2,3,4 and I have to show the 32 images in 8 rows. Please help me how can I do this. @adnan

Comment: It will look like a row if you cover 3 items in device width. and set collectionView width as device full width

Comment: I have to do this in a tableview, it's my task. :(

Comment: post your interface builder snap how you setting 4 image views in single tableview row prototype? if you are using storyboard ,you can assign tags to these imageviews and populate tableview as described by robin .(Number of rows in section should be  imagesount/numberOfimagesPerRow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    you have to add 4 imageview into tableviewcell
```

for this you need a customtableviewcell
then add
indexPath.row=4*indexPath.row;
imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1];
imageView3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]+2;
imageView4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+3];

Comment: I have taken 4 imageviews in my tableviewcell and i have set the tags as 1,2,3,4. @Robin

Comment: Just look at the method how I am taking the images from the string and showing into the imageviews.

Comment: there is no need of setting tags.. just try with above code in cellForRowAtIndexpath

Comment: In this way can I show 32 images in 8 rows? With 4 images per row?

Comment: sure.. you can display 4 images per row.. hope you have 4 imageviews in your tableviewcell

Comment: but dude! How can the compiler identify which image is for which one in the storyboard without tags?

Comment: Your logic is right but you have to get the compiler identified the imageviews with tags.

Comment: FirstRow imageView1 will get first image, second will get second image and so on.. Second row. imageview1 will get 5th image  etc..  hope u r expecting this.. did you tried my code??

Comment: did u set up 4 imageviews in storyboard?? then use imageviewoutlets for identifing imagview...imageview1,imageView2....

Answer (score 1):

```
This is how i have populated 2 images in one row you can follow these line to populate 4 image in one row , like take remainder of array count with 4 and if remainder is 0 then total number of rows will be array.count/4 .   


  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {

        if ([[Globals sharedInstance].couponsArray count]%2==0)
        {
            return [[Globals sharedInstance].couponsArray count]/2;
        }
        else
        {
            return [[Globals sharedInstance].couponsArray count]/2+1;
        }



    }
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell1";
        //    int currentRow = [indexPath row];


        CustomCell1 *cell = (CustomCell1*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
        if (cell == nil){
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell1" owner:self options:nil];
            for (id object in nib) {
                if([object isKindOfClass:[CustomCell1 class]])
                    cell = (CustomCell1*)object;
            }

        }

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[CustomCell1 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        NSLog(@"here is indexPath %d",indexPath.row);

        int index= indexPath.row*1+indexPath.row;
        int index1= index+1;


        if ([Globals sharedInstance].couponsArray.count/2>=indexPath.row)
        {
        [cell.indicater1 stopAnimating];
        [cell.indicater2 stopAnimating];
        }

        NSString* imageURLString = [[[Globals sharedInstance].couponsArray objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"coupon_image"];
        NSURLRequest* imageRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURLString]
                                                      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                                  timeoutInterval:60];

         [cell.indicater1 setCenter:cell.carImage.center];
         [cell.indicater1 startAnimating];

        [cell.carImage setImageWithURLRequest:imageRequest
                             placeholderImage:nil
                                      success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image)
        {
                                          [cell.indicater1 stopAnimating];
                                          [cell.carImage setImage:image];

                                          NSLog(@"Image must be Loaded here");
                                      }
                                      failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                          [cell.indicater1 stopAnimating];
                                      }];





        [cell.btn1 setTag:index];
        [cell.btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];





        if (index1>[Globals sharedInstance].couponsArray.count-1)
        {


            cell.carImage1.hidden=YES;
            cell.lblModel_car1.hidden=YES;
            cell.secondndImage.hidden=YES;
            cell.indicater2.hidden=YES;
            cell.indicater1.hidden=YES;
            cell.triangleImage.hidden=YES;


        }

        else
        {

            NSString* imageURLString1 = [[[Globals sharedInstance].couponsArray objectAtIndex:index1] objectForKey:@"coupon_image"];
            NSURLRequest* imageRequest1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURLString1]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                                       timeoutInterval:600];

             [cell.indicater2 setCenter:cell.carImage1.center];
             [cell.indicater2 startAnimating];

            [cell.carImage1 setImageWithURLRequest:imageRequest1
                                  placeholderImage:nil
                                           success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                               [cell.indicater2 stopAnimating];
                                               [cell.carImage1 setImage:image];

                                               NSLog(@"Image must be Loaded here");
                                           }
                                           failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                               [cell.indicater2 stopAnimating];
                                           }];



            [cell.btn2 setTag:index1];
            [cell.btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        }


        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        return cell;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set image view of uitableViewCell?
Try this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableCell"];

_patternsString = [self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_patternsString];

return cell;
}
```

Hope it helps you. If you are designing a custom cell (not using system imageView of tableViewCells), probably you need create a custom TableViewCell.

Comment: I have tried this, it shows one image in one row but I want to show 4 images in one row. How to do that? @robygam

Comment: Assuming you are using storyboards: 
(1) Put a cell into tableView and configure with style you want.
(2) Create a new class subclassing from UITableViewCell.
(3) Write in custom class property of cell your custom class created.
(4) Link with assistant editor your storyboard with new class creating properties in .h/.m
(5) Instead of UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableCell"]; Type cell as your custom tableViewCell class.
(6) Now in your cellForRowAtIndexPath you can access and set each image.
If you have not solved yet hope this helps you @Tirthendu